# Manipulate view controller classes from an independent class

Tags: objective-c, class, view, controller

I have 2 view controller classes and 1 independent class that i included the view controller headers.
I want to change from 1st view to another calling them in my independent class.
I try some thing like this but with no chance..

```
    Tab1_ViewController *tab1 = [[Tab1_ViewController alloc]init];

    Tab1_Login_ViewController *tab2 = [[Tab1_Login_ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"Tab1_Login_ViewController" bundle:@"nil];

    [tab1.navigationController pushViewController:tab2 animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

That should work fine, Provided you've already got `tab1` on the screen, (and with a working `navigation controller` set up)